# If length in a frame moving with respect to a stationary frame contracts, how do we define the speed of the moving frame?

Tags: special-relativity

Under Galilean transformations, the speed of a moving system $k$ with respect to a stationary system $K$ is straightforward. Assuming the origins of $k$ and $K$ coincide at t=0, the spatial coordinates of $k$ are related to those of $K$ with time as follows:

$$ x' = x-vt $$

To demonstrate the speed of $k$ with respect to $K$ within a Galilean system, we can find how the distance between any pair of points from $K$ and $k$ coinciding at $t=0$ varies per unit time. Let $x_0$ be a stationary point in $K$ and $x_k$ be a point in $K$ which moves along the path of a stationary point $x'_0$ in k. Let us set the stationary points to have an equal and constant value: $x_0= x'_0 = C$. Let the moving point $x_k$ in $K$ be described as follows:

$$ x'_0 = x_k - v t \implies x_k = x'_0 + vt  = C + vt$$

The speed of $k$ with respect to $K$ is then:

$$\frac{x_k - x_0}{t} = \frac{C + vt - C}{t}  = v $$

This shows that no matter which choice of coinciding initial points we make in our analysis, the speed of $k$ with respect to $K$ is $v$. In the special theory of relativity, it seem this is only true for the origin:

$$ x'_0 = \gamma(x_k - v t) \implies x_k = \frac{x'_0}{\gamma} + vt  = \frac{C}{\gamma} + vt$$
$$\frac{x_k - x_0}{t} = \frac{\frac{C}{\gamma} + vt - C}{t}  = \frac{ C (\frac{1}{\gamma} - 1)}{t} + v = \frac{ C (1 - \gamma)}{\gamma t} + v$$

Therefore, only if we choose to analyze the origin does the speed of $k$ with respect to $K$ remain $v$. But, the origin can be chosen to be anywhere arbitrarily so this shouldn't be so. Do the laws of physics really depend on my choice of origin?

Comment: For $\frac{x_k - x_K}{\Delta t}$ to makes sense, $x_k$ is the co-ordinate that the non-moving observer thinks the moving observer has at time $t$ while $x_K$ is the same for time $0$. Let's write this as $\frac{x_k - x_0}{\Delta t}$. This should vanish for $t = 0$ but your formula turns it into $\frac{x_0}{\Delta t} \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{\gamma} \right )$.

Comment: You are correct, $x_k$ is the coordinate of the moving observer in the non-moving frame with time. You can see I eventually replace $x_K$ with $x_0$ in my expressions. My simplifications are correct. Have any thoughts about the actual subject matter at hand?

Comment: Basically, when people say k moves with velocity v wrt to K, they are talking about the origins ... but I can choose the origin to be anywhere. STR says length contraction occurs around the origin i.e. if k has a speed of 1 space unit for 1 time unit, after 1 time unit has elapsed point 0 in k will move to point 1 in K, but point 1 in k will move to less than point 2 in K. The choice of origin seems to be significant ...

Comment: Your simplifications are not all correct because they allow you to calculate the same quantity in two different ways and the answers are different. This quantity is the position of the moving observer in the non-moving frame at $t = 0$.

Comment: You're right ... at t=0, my expression goes to infinity. Something is wrong. But, it isn't the simplification ... it's the analysis.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I misunderstood the original question. The actual question is just a math one, why do we get the same speed regardless of which point we choose in the moving coordinate system. The answer is that both time and space need to be transformed, i.e. we need to apply the full Lorentz transforms.

For any arbitrary fixed $x_0$ in the "moving" frame, the path it traces out in its rest frame is the set $(t, x_0)$. which corresponds to the path $\gamma(t+vx_0, x_0+tv)$ in the "stationary" frame. But note that we assume $v$ and $x_0$ are constant, so let us re-parameterize the path with $T = \gamma(t + vx_0)$; then:

$t = \frac{T}{\gamma} - vx_0$

and so

$\gamma(x_0 + tv) = \gamma x_0 + \gamma(\frac{T}{\gamma} - vx_0) v
 = Tv + C$ for some constant $C$

(remember that $\gamma$, $v$, and $x_0$ are all constant; we could work out $C$, but it's tedious and irrelevant).

The path $(t, x) = (t, x_0)$ in moving coordinates is thus expressed as $(T, X) = (T, vT + C)$ in stationary coordinates; in other words it obeys the equation $X = vT + C$ where $T$ is the (Earth) time. The slope is $v$, and so we see that the initial choice of $x_0$ affected only the offset $C$ and not the speed that we calculate.

Original answer:

You can define the speed in any coordinate system, and it's relative to that coordinate system. The speed is simply $\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$ where $x$ and $t$ are as measured in the specific coordinate system in question. Let's call this the "stationary" coordinate system. It's irrelevant that there is length contraction in  the "moving" coordinate system, because that's not the system we're using to define the speed: we're defining it relative to the "stationary" coordinates. In fact the speed relative to the "moving" coordinates (moving along with the object) is always 0.

Comment: I've defined the speed of the moving system with respect to stationary. In a Galilean system, each point of the moving system moves away from its initial position in the stationary system with speed v. But, in STR if v=1, 0 in k moves to 1 in K at t=1, but 1 in k moves to less than 2 in K. So the speed of point 1 in k wrt to point 1 in K is not v due to length contraction. So what is v? Speed of origin wrt to origin. But, origin is arbitrary.

Comment: Ah, gotcha, I misunderstood your question. You have to use the full Lorentz transformation (not just length contraction) to solve the problem. I'll edit my answer shortly to reflect this.

Comment: Right, you did a complete transform from moving (t,x) to stationary (T,X). Gonna take me some time to understand this intuitively. This mixing of space and time is a puzzler. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I think where you went wrong in your calculations was where you said: "Let us set the stationary points to have an equal and constant value: $x_0=x′_0=C$." You haven't specified the times associated with those points, and because of the relativity of simultaneity that matters. In general since the frames are moving relative to one another, that equality will hold only at a specific time, and the two frames will assign different values to that time.

Comment: Or more accurately, the events $(t_0, C)$ (stationary frame) and $(t'_0, C)$ (moving frame) are different events in spacetime.